# express.static not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I have the below code

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');

    });

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

But when executing `localhost:3000/Home.html` where Home.html is the html file inside my public directory its saying Cannot GET /Home.html.
I dont know what mistake i did.
Please correct me.

Comment: I just ran your code locally and it works fine for me. What's the name of your `public` directory? Would you happen to have the code on a public Git repo (Github, Bitbucket, Gitlab...)? What's you version of NodeJS (run `node -v` to find out)? Are you on Windows?

Comment: my node version is v4.2.4 name of my public folder is public

Comment: am trying to run in ubuntu in gedit in the line express.statc the word static is highlighted in red is it  a problem?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post that information. No, using "static" is not be a problem. As I said, your code works for me. Try running `chmod -R +r .` in the folder that contains your Node website. And then try starting your server again. What does the console say? Is `Home.html` available then?

Comment: @conradk sry my public folder was "Public" and in the code i used :public" that was the reason for error. Thanks a lot for ur help..